# Timer does not stop

Tags: flutter, dart

**Problem**

I'm doing a chat. I want the program to try to get messages again every 5 seconds if there are no messages.

**My solution**

I'have created a Timer in my stateful widget.

```
Timer timer;
```

When I build a widget, I check for messages. If there are none, I start the timer. I want the timer to stop at the next check, in case of existing messages

```
void onBuild() {
    if (state.messages.isEmpty) {
      _checkEmptyMessages();
      timer = Timer.periodic(
          Duration(seconds: 5), (Timer t) => _checkEmptyMessages());
    }
}



void _checkEmptyMessages() {
    print('MES789 ${state.messages.isEmpty}');
    if (state.messages.isEmpty) {
      add(ChatEventLoadFirstPage()); // This adds an event to the BLoC
    } else {
      if (timer != null) timer.cancel();
      timer = null;
    }
  }
```

**Also I've tried**

I've tried to remove `timer = null;` and *await* for `timer.cancel();`, but it didn't help.

**Actual output**

So in the Debug Console I get this every 5 seconds:

I/flutter (13387): MES789 false

I/flutter (13387): MES789 false

I/flutter (13387): MES789 false

I/flutter (13387): MES789 false

**Question**

How can I stop the Timer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because 'Timer.periodic' is called, new Timer instance is created and stored same timer variable.

It means that not canceled timer's instance will be lost when 'Timer.periodic' is called.

So you need to check whether Timer instance is exist.

```
void onBuild() {
  if (state.messages.isEmpty) {
      if (timer == null) {
          timer = Timer.periodic(
              Duration(seconds: 5), (Timer t) => add(ChatEventLoadFirstPage()));
      }
   }  else {
      if (timer != null) timer.cancel();
      timer = null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

this code is dead code, it will never work because you have `if (state.messages.isEmpty)` before `_checkEmptyMessages()` and `if (state.messages.isEmpty)` again, try to remove first `if (state.messages.isEmpty)`

Comment: The logic is definitely not perfect, but the `_checkEmptyMessages()` doesn't depends on first "if", so it's not a problem, but the first "if" could have the "else" branch to cancel the timer.

Comment: depends, the answer above just solves this problem, as well as my answer